# Axis label in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

This code:

```
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    .HasTitle = True
    .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Issues"
End With
```

It adds the label to the X axis, but it also preserves the old. I want to change or remove the old label to this one.
Now I have two labels/titles below the x axis.

Comment: I've just ran your code in excel 2007 and it didn't preserve the old title on a standard bar chart. What kind of chart are you using and how many datasets does it have?

Comment: I am using columnclustered.
I have 6 seriescollection. and under the chart it displays the name of the first.

Comment: As I answered on the previous topic, if you use F2 to go into Object Explorer in Microsoft VBA, it is not useful to use `Characters` (maybe regarding your excel version) so just use `.AxisTitle.Text =` and it should be good

Comment: I think I maybe got it wrong.. I guess what I need to change is the values on the X axis.. but when calling ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues, I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the old axis title first, try this :

```
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    .AxisTitle.Delete
    .HasTitle = True
    .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Issues"
End With
```